# intersectionobserver inside useEffect only fires once

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to make style class on and off when it is observed, but it works only once. i guess it may be solved with obs.unobserve or obs.disconnect, but i failed to write a code in right way.
Here is the code. (simplified)

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const obs = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {

                    $('.class-a').addClass('white');
                }
                else {
                   
                    $('.class-a').addClass('black');
                }

            })
        }, { threshold: [0.5] });
        obs.observe(document.querySelector('.sub'));

    }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only querying a single selector. If you want to query more than one, you would have to use `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Edit try this (querying them on their own won't work, have to actually loop through them as well):

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.sub');
list.forEach((el) => {
  obs.observe(el);
})
```

Referring to [these mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/observe)

Working non-react test: https://codepen.io/shikkaba/pen/eYMVXXX

Comment: i don't know why but when i use obs.observe(document.querySelectorAll('.sub')); it doesnt work :(

Comment: You don't have anything removing a class, so both classes would stay active. I can't see your code other than the js, so I can't really tell if that's part of the problem you're experiencing, but that would be an issue with this.

Comment: Okay, while what I noted is valid, it wouldn't have fixed your issue. I edited my answer. See if that helps. :)